# Git and CakePHP 3

Tags: git, cakephp-3.0

What is the best practice in adding a CakePHP 3 project to git? In CakePHP 2 I would add the entire app director minus tmp and .htaccess and it would be great. In CakePHP 3 the project or app folder now contains various vendor files that should be preferably loaded using composer. I would appreciate any insight into some best practices for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this as the content of your `.gitignore` file

```
/vendor/*
/config/app.php
/tmp/*
/logs/*

.htaccess
/webroot/.htaccess
```

By that only your relevant files will be pushed with git. If you commit your composer.lock file than you could have the same versions of all packages insalled by composer.

Answer (score 1):

I work with Git and Cakephp3, and add all folders, but excluding vendors,tmp and excluding app.php from config folders.

Answer (score 0):

I work with git and I add the whole planet since I dont have bandwidth limitation or time problem. But if you want to add the minimum you can add these folders only :

- config
- plugins
- src
- webroot